# This cache store does not support tagging with Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

each time when i try to authenticate (default laravel authentification) on my laravel app, when i submit my form, i have this error :

> BadMethodCallException
> This cache store does not support tagging.

I need to resfresh my browser, and it work juste fine ! I'am not able to know why or to find the error

And i am note able to find why this happen ! This the link to the error
https://flareapp.io/share/xmN6A88m#F82

I use PHP8 / Laravel 8 / JetStream

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set your cache driver to file inside of your `.env` to file, set instead to:

```
CACHE_DRIVER=array
```

Setting to Redis might work too